# Configuring indexes in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-indexes

this is my first time dealing with indexes and would like to understand few things.

I have the tables of the following schemas:

### Table1: Customer details

| id | name | createdOn | username | phone | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | some date | xyz12 | 12345678 | abc |

The `id` in the above table is unique. The `id` is not defined as PK in the table though. Would `id` + `createdOn` be a good complex index?

### Table2: Tracked customer actions

| customer id | name | timestamp | action type | cart value | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | some date | click | . | abc |

The above table does not have any column with unique values and there can be a lot of sparse data. The above actions table is a sample and can have almost 18 columns, with new data being added frequently. Is having `all` columns as a index a good one?

The queries on these tables could be both simple and complex as below:

```
select * from customerDetails

OR 

with target_customers as (
  select 
    id as customer_id
  from customerDetails
  where customer_date > {some date}

)
select avg(cart_value) from actions a
where action_type = 'cart updated'
inner join target_customers b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

These are sample queries and I believe I will be having even more complex queries using different aggregations and joins with other tables as well to gain insights while performing analytics in the future.

I want to understand the best columns for indexes on the above tables.

Comment: Indexes resolve slowness for specific queries. Please include the queries you want to optimize.

Comment: Your questions basically cannot be answered. What makes a good (usable) index is highly dependent upon how the data is accessed (i.e. `join`, `where` clauses). Without knowing that you cannot say whether any index is good.  As far as a PK you essentially have it assuming `id` is also `not null` as the attributes of PK are not null, unique. Having an (single) index on all columns is generally a bad idea - you have essentially copied the table ordered by the columns.

Comment: `select * from customerDetails` -- No index necessary. You are retrieving the entire heap.

Comment: The second (more complex) query is not a valid query in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this query?

Answer (score 0):

> *The id is not defined as PK in the table though.*"

That's unusual. Why is that?

> *Would id + createdOn be a good complex index?*

No, you'd reverse it: `createdOn, id`. An index can use the first column alone. This allows you to use the index to `order by createdOn` and also `createdOn between X and Y`.

But you probably wouldn't include `id` in there at all. Make `id` a primary key and it is indexed.

In general, if you want to cover all possibilities for two keys, make two indexes...

- columnA, columnB
- columnB

`columnA, columnB` can cover queries which only reference columnA and can also order by columnA. It can also cover queries which reference both columnA and columnB. But it can't cover a query which only references columnB, so we need an single-column index for columnB.

> *Is having all columns as a index a good one?*

Maybe, it depends on your queries, but probably not.

You want to index foreign keys, they should be indexed automatically, because that will speed up all joins.

You probably want to index timestamps that you're going to search or order by.

Any flags you often query by, such as `where action_type = 'cart updated'` you may want to index. Or you may want to partition the table by the action type.

> *The above actions table is a sample and can have almost 18 columns, with new data being added frequently.*

This *may* be a good use of a single `jsonb` column to store all the miscellaneous attributes. This allows you to use [a single index for the jsonb column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). However, jsonb is not a panacea and you will have to choose what to put in jsonb and what to make columns.

For example, a timestamp such as `createdOn` should probably be a column. Also any foreign keys. And status flags such as `action_type`.